# Left and right navigation in horizontal listview in winjs

Tags: javascript, listview, windows-store-apps, winjs

How do we implement like Windows store does? Left and right navigational arrows with animations for 'Listview'? I tried, 'Flipview', 'HubControl', and also, when ever I try 'ensureVisible' on 'Listview', there are no animations in 'Listview'. How do I achieve animating content while navigating with left and right arrows?

Comment: The `FlipView` should do it... what have you tried so far? what do you see? maybe you're missing some properties

Comment: @sebagomez, I need pagination in list view. So Flipview, dint help in that

Comment: what about the `ListView` with `GroupLayout`?

Comment: I don't get arrows with them. All paging code should be written manually

Comment: FYI, if the store app is still written in HTML5/JavaScript, you can actually try to peek at the source by looking at the app code itself.  It's under your local drive\Program Files\WindowsApps.  It will in a folder with a combination app name + guid. Should be recognizable.  You'll see the HTML in there.  All you need to do is assume ownership of the folder to get access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, misunderstood your question before.  I think you'll have to use a ListView and draw your own buttons on a layer above it.

When you push a button, you can get the current scroll position of the ListView using the scrollPosition property.  Get the current width of the ListView and add to or subtract that from the scrollPosition.  However, this does not animate the scrolling automatically.

You can also use the ensureVisible() method to scroll to a particular item.

To get the ListView to animate when jumping to a new position, I think you're going to have to use WinJS.UI.executeAnimation to do it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779762.aspx

I've done it before, but I honestly can't remember exactly how it works.  I know you'll have to setup some rules for how the animation behaves in CSS and then run it asynchronously in javascript.

Comment: I have tried same and its working flawlessly. Instead of using scrollposition, I used, indexofFirstVisible. For animations, I have used, turnstileforwardin. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

WinJS.UI.Pivot has arrows with ListViews in the playground.
http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#pivot

So does WinJS.UI.FlipView
http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#flipview

But maybe you want the WinJS.UI.NavBar
http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#navbar

Comment: NavBar might help me. But, thats deprecated in latest version